# Windows audio isn't always active

Tags: windows-10, audio

I have an MSI GS63VR laptop running Windows 10, and I made this awesome sound scheme for all my desktop sound effects, but the beginning of the sound gets cut off because it seems the playback goes to "sleep" when no sound is being output for a few seconds. If 2 sounds play in close succession the second one is perfect, but if there's silence it takes about half a second for the sound to kick in when triggered - normally wouldn't be a problem but the sound itself is only half a second long.

Couple notes:

1. this happens with any audio interface: built-in speakers, standard headphones, USB headphones, etc.
2. for some reason if I have Windows Movie Maker open in the background all will behave correctly.  Not sure if that's overriding the audio sleep, however this is the only program I've found that does that.  I've also tried Premiere Pro and Audacity without success.
3. also noted if I have a YouTube video paused in the background it will behave correctly for about a minute and then go back to cutting out

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried adding a second of empty sound to your effect(s)? Are they .wav files, if not they should be. If so, maybe the .wav file should be a little lower in compression.

Comment: I have tried an empty second to no avail; they are .wav and I don't think they're very compressed. I also get the same behavior when playing them directly from Audacity. Also just discovered if I have a YouTube video paused in the background it will behave correctly for about a minute and then go back to cutting off.

Comment: Could be the way Windows driver(s) are handling the output. One is less important so it has the delay. I can only guess. In Services "Windows Audio Endpoint Builder", could be called differently on your computer, might be the cause, make sure it is set to Automatic.

Comment: I have had an issue with Windows 10 and audio in the past, it could be your computer was updated with only Microsoft drivers, you might want to check your drives for the audio device in Device Manager, maybe you can find an update for the driver(s) for the hardware from the vendor. I had to replace mine with a true Intel audio driver, then it worked correctly. MS is good for that, so-called universal drivers. Good luck, I hope I helped, at least a little. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to user [vssher](https://superuser.com/users/1107618/vssher) whose [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1553344/solved-windows-audio-isnt-always-active#comment2362979_1553344) prompted me to update the audio drivers in device manager, and presto, everything now works.

> **[vssher's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1553344/solved-windows-audio-isnt-always-active#comment2362979_1553344)**
> I have had an issue with Windows 10 and audio in the past, it could be your computer was updated with only Microsoft drivers, you might want to check your drives for the audio device in Device Manager, maybe you can find an update for the driver(s) for the hardware from the vendor. I had to replace mine with a true Intel audio driver, then it worked correctly. MS is good for that, so-called universal drivers. Good luck, I hope I helped, at least a little. Peace.
> – vssher May 20, 2020 ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/1553344/solved-windows-audio-isnt-always-active#comment2362979_1553344))

Comment: Glad it all worked out. We all learn something everyday ;-p

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem very recently of the Windows Audio going to sleep, which would cause my external speaker to make a humming noise similar to when the laptop is off (newly purchased `ryzen 5 7520u`, fresh install `Win 10 LTSC 2021` on new nvme drive).   Anytime I played music or did anything requiring sound, the speaker worked normally.  But after about 10 seconds, problem returned.

> for some reason if I have Windows Movie Maker open in the background all will behave normally

So I did actually run into [the answer on a different forum](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/realtek-hd-audio-no-sound-after-idle-for-5-seconds.2703732/post-21911000) and will copy it here with some screenshots for context.  It appears that Microsoft did something to how it handles audio to where you need to have some program sending audio of some kind in order for the audio driver to never "sleep" when computer sound is idle.

### Edit with  simpler method:

Play music in app at very low volume to prevent speaker from sleeping.   I decided to use [Ambie](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9P07XNM5CHP0?hl=en-us) (unfortunately only available via Microsoft Store), but any music player could work.   Play it at 1% volume.  And then you can Open Volume Mixer from the Audio tray icon context menu and further lower the volume of the audio player app (50% or lower)  .

[image: ambie 1% volume setting][image: Windows Volume Mixer Settings]

So you cannot hear it playing, but the computer thinks it is playing, which prevents the speaker from sleeping.

For additional automation, you can setup either a Task Scheduler or otherwise load the player on startup.

MS Store apps have a hard time being able to fully function from startup unattended (for "Security" reasons).  But Ambie has a 1-click startup option, where it will issue a Windows Notification to remind you to click on that notification which will start the player.

---

---OLDER method---

**Fast way to Sound Device Properties.** 
`Sound Tray Icon [context menu] > Sounds >`

[image: tray icon sound context right click menu]

Recording tab > Stereo Mix is <kbd>Enabled</kbd>

[image: recording tab--Stereo Mix Enabled]

**Slow way to Sound Device Properties**

Go to `System Settings > Sound` from taskbar search or right-click Sound tray icon

   Select <kbd>Manage Sound Devices</kbd>

[image: System Settings--Sound menu]

There should be a list of devices for Input and Output.

 In the Input section, make sure `Stereo Mix` is <kbd>enabled</kbd>

[image: Enable Stereo Mix input]

Go back to `Sound settings > Input >` and choose <kbd>Stereo Mix</kbd> as the device and select <kbd>Device Properties</kbd>.
[image: (long way): Choose Stereo Mix and Device Properties]

---

`Stereo Mix > Properties >` <kbd>Listen tab</kbd>

Make sure `Listen to this device` is <kbd>checked</kbd>
Power Management `Continue running when on battery power` radio button is selected
[image: stereo mix properties--Listen tab]

`Levels` Tab place the stereo Mix Level to 0.

[image: Stereo Mix--Levels tab]

But you can slide it higher towards 100 very briefly to hear the white noise


This sends an undetectable amount of white noise such that the system will think it is constantly playing some kind of audio.

Now if only the other problem of `laptop screen off results in system sleep` could be resolved.